# с каким ключом COUNT() sql падает в массив $result

Tags: php, sql

делаю запрос к двум таблицам, через count получаю кол-во коментариев.

```
SELECT news.id, news.title, news.date, news.author_name, news.short_content,COUNT(comm.comment)
        FROM php_base.news AS news 
        LEFT JOIN php_base.comments AS comm 
        ON news.id = comm.news_id
        GROUP BY news.id, news.title, news.date, news.author_name, news.short_content
        ORDER BY news.date DESC LIMIT 10
```

дальше циклом

```
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
            $newsList[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
            $newsList[$i]['title'] = $row['title'];
            $newsList[$i]['date'] = $row['date'];
            $newsList[$i]['author_name'] = $row['author_name'];
            $newsList[$i]['short_content'] = $row['short_content'];
            $newsList[$i]['???'] = $row['comment'];
            $i++;
```

вопрос в том с каким ключом count падает в $result

Comment: Если не использовать алиасы, то поле так и будет называться COUNT(comm.comment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте алиасы в запросе

```
...COUNT(comm.comment) as cnt...
$count = $result['cnt']
```